# Replacing mic22705 buck converter with cheaper one

Tags: dc-dc-converter, microchip, texas-instruments, step-down

Since Microchip decided to increase their [mic22705](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50lyoh1j0ca4crb/mic22705.pdf?dl=0) price, my company decided to replace it with another synchronous buck converter. the current price we get for 20K units of [mic22705](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50lyoh1j0ca4crb/mic22705.pdf?dl=0) is 1.459$.

The board on which I will be doing the redesign uses *Vin_Root* voltage source which has the following product specifications for customers: Min = 3.3V, Typical: 5v, Max = 5.5v.

The [mic22705](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50lyoh1j0ca4crb/mic22705.pdf?dl=0) device is used 3 times in order to create the following voltages: 3.3V, 1.5V, 1.2V (pay attention to the power sequence order):

[image]
[image]
[image]

One solution was to use [tps54719](https://www.dropbox.com/s/medlmh6z3do65pd/tps54719.pdf?dl=0) as an alternative. the problem that I can't create Vout=3.3V from Vin=3.3V, which is a special case. (the simulation in https://webench.ti.com/ fails as a reason of exceeding duty cycle limit).

I heard some devices have *bypass mode*, this also can be an option in the solution I'm looking for, but I didn't dive into details\examples.

On the other hand, I'm not sure all our customers are really dependent on supplying 3.3V voltage input, and I'm not sure someone actually tried to supply 3.3V to [mic22705](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50lyoh1j0ca4crb/mic22705.pdf?dl=0) to see if it even works. but I have somehow to consider then option.

Questions:

1. is there a way to know if [mic22705](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50lyoh1j0ca4crb/mic22705.pdf?dl=0) can supply *Vout=3.3V* when *Vin=3.3V* even before trying to physically trying to make an ECO to the board and see it's output?
2. looking at [mic22705](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50lyoh1j0ca4crb/mic22705.pdf?dl=0) datasheet, I was confused by the following graph, which shows that for Vin = 3.3V, the output current is very small (around zero):

[image]

Does that that mean that for Vout=3.3V, Vin=3.3V I can be sure that even if one of our customers tried to supply "Vin=3.3V" and still our product worked fine for him, then surely the *VPER_3P3* was consuming a very small current? does that mean I can replace only the first converter with other TI step down converter where it's Vin:3.3V-5.5V and it's able to create Vout=3.3V with lower amperage than [mic22705](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50lyoh1j0ca4crb/mic22705.pdf?dl=0) 7A maximal output current?

Note: the idea is to use only two [tps54719](https://www.dropbox.com/s/medlmh6z3do65pd/tps54719.pdf?dl=0) devices and the third is another device which will be chosen according to what I mentioned above.

Update: the reason that the 3 converters were chosen to be [mic22705](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50lyoh1j0ca4crb/mic22705.pdf?dl=0), is that for the third voltage (that goes for the SoC), there is a high current consumption mode when the CPU is 100% consumed. and the designer wanted to choose a uniform DC2DC for the 3 voltages just because it's more comfort. but now, I see that *Up to 7A* for the three DCDC's might be too much. I'm trying to set a new maximal current limit by looking at the [CPU Datasheet](https://www.micro-semiconductor.com/datasheet/97-MCIMX6Q5EYM10AD.pdf) again. I summed all the currents in this table, and what I got is 6.260 [A]. can I set 6.3 [A] as the new maximal amperage delivery for the new 3 DCDC's?
[image]

Comment: What is the required current for each of the three output voltages?

Comment: Please see my Update. I'm only doing a re-design for the 3 DC2DC's and I'm not familiar with the whole project. I need to do some research for the current required for 3 voltages, but at least I know why they decided for 7[A] maximal delivery for the 3 DC2DC's (its because of the CPU voltage). I'm sure the other 2 voltages don't consume that much, maybe maximum 3 [A]. but I need to check that. I'm also thinking about to measure (on board) the maximum current when the CPU is 100% consumed, but this is tricky, since I don't have current sense resistors.